# ASP.net MVC Entity Data Model Class Serialize Problem

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to serialize my Entity Data Model Class I try to change ICollection to List and HashSet to List but didn't work i can't fix it.

```
    public partial class Product
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Product()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my asmx code

```
 public class VisualWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public Product AddNewProduct(Product _product)
    {
        try
        {
            ProductDb productDb = new ProductDb();
            _product = productDb.AddNewProduct(_product);

            return _product;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When are you serializing it, do you need it for a HTTP request? If so, will you include that?

Comment: Actually i learn new these, and i just added .net empty library, and in the .net c# web service one asmx file. I edit my question and add my asmx code

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is it not properly serialized? Do you get an error message?